# Получить исходный код фрейма

Tags: iframe, chrome-extension

Как можно с помощью chrome extension получить исходный код фрейма как он есть без того, что потом модифицируют скрипты?
Пробовал так:

```
    chrome.webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded.addListener(d => {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(d.tabId, { code: `
                if(window.top != window.self)
                    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(chrome.runtime.id, { message: 'html', data: document.documentElement.outerHTML } );
                `, frameId: d.frameId });
    });
```

Не работает (все равно скрипты успевают модифицировать).
С помощью Ajax'а нельзя делать, потому что на один и тот же url может быть разный контент (динамический фрейм).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нормальными средствами (chrome.webRequest) никак.

Можно попробовать очень тяжелую артиллерию - [chrome.debugger API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger).

Вкратце: приаттачиться к странице (Chrome покажет при этом желтое предупреждение вверху), а потом отправить команду [getResponseBody](https://chromedevtools.github.io/debugger-protocol-viewer/1-1/Network).